# Cross-sell products are different in admin panel and UI

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, cross-sells

I have added cross-sells products for my product in the Admin panel of Magento 2.

Still, on UI its shows different product.

The helper function for getting cross-sell products is

```
 public function getCrossSellProducts(){
    $currentProduct = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    $collection =  $currentProduct->getCrossSellProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(8);
    $this->_crossSellProducts =  $collection->load();
    return $this->_crossSellProducts;
}
```

Still, it shows different products than my admin panel products which I added.

What's the issue?

Where cross-sell products are stored in database/ tables

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `catalog_product_link` table and `link_type_id` field equal to `5` is cross_sell product type, for other related types you can refer to `catalog_product_link_type` table.

```
public function getCrossSellProducts(){
        /*$currentProduct = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
        $collection =  $currentProduct->getCrossSellProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(8);
        $this->_crossSellProducts =  $collection->load();
        return $this->_crossSellProducts;*/
        // debugg code sample
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        // $id is debugged current product id
        $currentProduct = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class)->load($id);
        $crossSellIds = $currentProduct->getCrossSellProductIds();
//        $collection =  $currentProduct->getCrossSellProductCollection();
//        $sqlString = $collection->getSelectSql()->__toString();
//        echo $sqlString;die;
        var_dump($crossSellIds);
    }
```

Comment: In catalog_product_link table, there are 8 products with link_type_id = 5 but there are only 2 products in my cross-sells admin panel, none of this matches with  catalog_product_link table list

Comment: This is not possible, it should be noted that the catalog_product_linl table product_id is row_id, you can use getCrossSellProductIds function for debugging?

Comment: What SQL query does getCrossSellProductIds internally uses, how can I print SQL query which getCrossSellProductIds function uses?

Comment: Refer to my edited code for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is a store configuration in `Admin > Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Rule-based Product Relations`.
Please review your configuration for `Show Cross-Sell Products` in it.

There are three options like Selected, Rule-based and Both. 
Selected means it will show you products which are selected from the admin catalog product edit page. Rule-based means catalog rule is created in Promotions to display cross-sell products. So, the products from rule-based will be shown by this option. And the third option is Both Selected and Rule-based.

So, I suggest you to review this configuration.

Comment: it is Both Selected and rule based

Comment: So, this might be the reason it is showing different products.

Comment: What should be the option to be selected to match it from admin panel

Comment: Select the option Selected.